# How to support project references with multisolution model using VS2010/msbuild?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

How can VS2010/msbuild support project references with a multi-solution model?

The outdated Microsoft Patterns and practices article on ["Structuring solutions and projects"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx) lists three main models for partitioning solutions and projects:

- Single solution
- Partitioned single solution
- Multi-solution

The article mentions that a disadvantage of the multi-solution model is that it requires using file references instead of project references.

The article was written in Jan 2002, and there hasnt been a new version added since.

The MSBuild ["assembly resolution series"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/05/11/assembly-resolution-in-msbuild-and-visual-studio-series-introduction.aspx)
hasn't gotten off the ground either.

What good articles are there on best practices for models for partitioning solutions and projects within VS2010, covering allowing project references and advances with msbuild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the latest version in [patterns & practices: Team Development with Visual Studio Team Foundation Server](http://tfsguide.codeplex.com/)

Relevant bits described in:

- [Chapter 3 - Structuring Projects and Solutions in Source Control](http://tfsguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chapter%203%20-%20Structuring%20Projects%20and%20Solutions%20in%20Source%20Control&referringTitle=Home)
- [Chapter 4 - Structuring Projects and Solutions in Team Foundation
  Source Control](http://tfsguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chapter%204%20-%20Structuring%20Projects%20and%20Solutions%20in%20Team%20Foundation%20Source%20Control&referringTitle=Home)
- [Chapter 10 - Large Project Considerations](http://tfsguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chapter%2010%20-%20Large%20Project%20Considerations&referringTitle=Home)

Related SO questions:

- [Guidance on solution and project structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4405517/147211)
- [More on: Help Structuring VS2010 Solutions/Projects and TFS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5083614/147211)
- [Structuring projects & dependencies of large winforms applications in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/152053/147211)
- [Recommended number of projects in Visual Studio Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/529907/147211)